# Formula to count the number of different letters in a word

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

In sheets, suppose cell `A1` contains the word `CABBAGE`.

I want to put a formula into, say, cell `B1` that will count the number of different letters. So the output should be `5`, because there are 5 different letters in `CABBAGE`.

I have a formula that will do this, however it is cumbersome and I bet there is a way to do it more concisely.

The formula that works is:

`=if(isnumber(search("A",A1)),1,0) + if(isnumber(search("B",A1)),1,0) + ... + if(isnumber(search("Z",A1)),1,0)`

The formula adds 1 each time a letter is present in the word. I'm just not sure of the best way to consolidate the 26 terms into something more manageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to process only one cell, you can use this in B2 (supposing that cell is A2):

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(1,26)),A2))>0,1)))`

If you need to process an entire range of cells (say, A2:A), you can use this in B2 of a previously empty B2:B range:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CHAR(64+SEQUENCE(1,26)),A2:A)),1,0),SEQUENCE(26,1,1,0))))`

In short, these formulas try to `SEARCH` all 26 letters of the alphabet in the target cell(s), using an ASCII list generated by `CHAR` and `SEQUENCE`. Since the ASCII value of 'A' is 65, we can run the entire uppercase alphabet this way. And since `SEARCH` is case agnostic, we can search both uppercase and lowercase at the same time. `SEARCH` also stops searching at the first instance of a letter that it finds; so it won't count multiples of the letter. That is, if it is found at all, the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following formula

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(S1),"[\W|\d]",""),"(.)","$1 ")," "))
```

[image: Formula to count the number of unique letters in a word]

Functions used:

- [`COUNTUNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093405)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`LOWER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094083)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. I have not used all of those functions before so I appreciate the links to more info.